# Why it doesn't run the breakpoint?

Tags: ios, breakpoints

[image: screen-shoot]

As the picture above, I'm confused that Why it doesn't run the breakpoint (line77)?
And It will jump to line 84 from 71.

Comment: you should put breakpoint on line 74,81 also and wait for sometime it will definitely go to line 77 or line 74 or 81

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are initialising a mutable array on line number 71.
2. Code written from line number 73 to 82 is block of asynchronous network call. Asynchronous means while you are fetching data from the server, code below that block will execute. When it finishes getting data from server in case of success it will comes in success block and in case of failure it will come in failure block.

That’s why your array will return before getting populated from server. For better implementation write separate method or api class for fetching data from server and populate your array in that class.

Comment: OK, thank you. And I want to modify the tmpArr in the block area, do I need to add a  __block in front of the tmpArr?

Comment: yes you can do that way but still your return statement will execute before your array gets populated. Write that api call in separate method and then call that method in your viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear.

Answer (score 0):

Line 77 is part of a block object that will be invoked when the asynchronous `GET` method completes successfully.

If you let your program run and the call is successful you will hit the breakpoint.

Comment: How to solve it?  I  study ios by myself and don't know  how to use the asynchronous.

Comment: you should put breakpoint on line 74,81 also and wait for sometime it will definitely go to line 77 or line 74 or 81